# using css float without width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

and corresponding css:

```
.content {width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000}
.icon {width:40px; height:40px; background-color:maroon}
.icon, .text {float:left}
```

I want to align icon and text componenent in one line without using any relative and absolute width value.

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7kNSs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove CSS `float` property form `.text`

Try [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/rp7ze/)

**HTML** :

```
 <div class="content">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
   .content 
        {
      width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000;
        }
   .icon 
        {
        width:40px; height:40px; background-color:maroon; float:left;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove float form text class

html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
  .content {width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000}
.icon {width:40px; height:40px; background-color:maroon;float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is take out the .text div:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.
    Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.
    Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.
    Some long message text which is wrapped in two lines.
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

.content {width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000}
.icon {width:40px; height:40px; background-color:maroon}
.icon, .text {float:left}
```

Check the forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/tfrH6/

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this line   `.content {width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000}`
by this

```
#content { overflow: hidden;width:300px; margin:30px auto; border:1px solid #000}
```